# Getting the sequence of Gcov's executed lines information

Tags: c, testing, gcc, gcov

I'm trying to get the sequence of line of code executed by a test case. By using Gcov, the output `.gcov` file shows which line of codes are executed and how many times they are executed but no information about the sequence.

The problem is that I can't get the sequence of the executed lines. Let's use this program as an example:

```
//...
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { // line 8
    if(a > b) { // line 9
        // do something (line 10 - 15)
    } else { // line 16
        // do something (line 17 - 20)
    }
}
//...
```

For example with input `x`, the loop body will be iterated twice where the `true` branch of the `if` executed on the first iteration and then the `false` branch on the second iteration. On this example, the information about the sequence of executed lines that I want to get would be something like this `...-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-8-9-17-18-19-20-...`.

With Gcov, I can't get the information mentioned above because the `.gcov` file will only show that all the lines from both branch are executed. There is no way I can figure out the sequence whether line 10-15 or line 17-20 are executed first.

Is there a way of getting the sequence of executed lines with Gcov? Or is there any alternatives of doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcov` (and `-fprofile-arcs`) only store and process raw numbers, there is no branch history information.  The data you are looking for is simply not available.

[American Fuzzy Lop](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/) has a different form of instrumentation which covers some path-related information. See the [technical description](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/technical_details.txt).  You do not say what you actually want to achieve, so perhaps this is sufficient.

If you need to capture *any* form of execution trace, you could use a GDB script like this:

```
b main
r
while 1
s
end
```

It will need some post-processing because it is quite difficult to suppress unwanted GDB output.  For more elaborate data capture, you could use the [GDB Python interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).

Comment: I think it's too complicated for the thing that I want to achieve. To clear things up, I want something that when the input is executed, the lines execution sequence will be shown. (I'm sorry if things become more confusing. I can't put my thought into words that well especially in english )

Comment: Then you could perhaps use GDB scripting?

Comment: I was also thinking about that. I'll look further into it.